# input type="range" bug when changing the value too often

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, user-controls

I'm using `input type="range"` for two purposes at a time: as value input and value output. Imagine this as a video seekbar.

I've noticed that changing the range's value by mouse does not work if I update the value  programmatically.

See the fiddle. I test it on Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/2jt7d/

My idea how to solve this issue is to monitor `mousedown` and stop updating until the mouse is released.

Am I doing something wrong or this is rather a flaw in control's design?

Comment: Range has been designed to response to mousedown and dragging, I wouldn't call it flaw. Your idea to solve the problem should work.

Comment: The event oninput registers the value as it changes while you are dragging the slider, or if you click the mouse or use arrow keys to advance or decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/2jt7d/3/

```
var i = 0,
    max = 1000,
    timer,
    range = document.getElementById('range');

function iteration() {
    range.value = i;
    if (i < max) {
        i++;
        timer = setTimeout(iteration, 100);
    }
}

range.max = max;

range.onmousedown = function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

range.onmouseup = function () {
    i = this.value;
    iteration();
}

iteration();
```